# <object> is not a member of System.Web.HttpContext Error After Converting C# TO VB.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am trying out ASP.Net and  have been looking for tutorials for a survey project I am working on. The solution I found that seems to be feasible to my application plans was written in C# and I have tried my best to convert it to Visual Basic dot Net.

The problem I get is two errors:

> Error 1   'Question' is not a member of
> 'System.Web.HttpContext'. C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Visual Studio
> 2012\Projects\SurveyOnline\SurveyOnline\SurveyForm.aspx.vb    37  61  SurveyOnline
>
> Error 2   'Survey_Question' is not a member of
> 'System.Web.HttpContext'. C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Visual Studio
> 2012\Projects\SurveyOnline\SurveyOnline\SurveyForm.aspx.vb    37  61  SurveyOnline

The source code is:

```
Private Sub PopulateSurvey()
        btnSubmit.Enabled = True
        Dim questions As List(Of Question) = (From p In Context.Question Join q In Context.Survey_Questions On p.ID Equals q.QuestionID Where q.SurveyID = surveyid Select p).ToList()
        Dim tbl As New Table()
```

... I have use Entity Framework database first approach for the data model.

The error is coming from Context.Question and Context.Survey_Questions. I even tried declaring Question and Survey_Questions as Objects within the base class of the sub procedure but it is not working.

I do not know what is the root problem and how to fix it. What do I do to remove these errors?

Comment: First, The error is crystal-clear. You are trying to query the wrong object - Context. That is *not* an EF context, that is the HttpContext of the web request.

Comment: Second, learn ASP.NET and C#, don't try to "convert to VB.NET". If you can't understand what the code does, you won't be able to tell whether the converter worked or not. Hint: they never do. Besides, C# is the most popular .NET language by a huge margin. Almost all tutorials and blog posts are about C#. Not because Microsoft didn't like VB.NET. *Developers* didn't like VB.NET. Microsoft still produces the same documentation in C# and VB.NET version. Third party bloggers and courses don't

Comment: Finally, check [ASP.NET's own course secion](https://www.asp.net/learn) and the free courses in [Visual Studio Dev Essentials](https://www.visualstudio.com/dev-essentials/). These include 3 months access to Pluralsight's courses, [including those for ASP.NET](https://www.pluralsight.com/search?q=asp.net)